# R in sp package, want to know the meaning of index for a fullgrid object

Tags: r, geo, r-sp

So I am study about different object in this package:sp,
Right now, focus on points with topology: Spatial pixel and its full grid form: Spatial grid

```
attr = expand.grid(xc = 1:3, yc = 1:3)
grd.attr = data.frame(attr, z1 = 1:9, z2 = 9:1)
coordinates(grd.attr) = ~xc+yc
gridded(grd.attr)
gridded(grd.attr) = TRUE
```

after this operation, we get a Spatial pixel with coordinate xc,yc; and attributs z1,z2; and I input the command:

```
grd.attr[1:5, "z1"]
```

with no surprise, it gives me the first 5 value of attributes "z1"
but if I make change it to a full grid form by:

```
fullgrid(grd.attr) = TRUE
```

and suddenly, this command :

```
grd.attr[1:2, "z1"]
```

gives erros:

```
Error in matrix(idx, grd@cells.dim[2], grd@cells.dim[1], byrow = TRUE)[rows,  : no 'dimnames' attribute for array
```

it seems this command

```
grd.attr[1:2,-2, "z1"]
```

gives me the first 6 attributes of z1
but I don't get exact meaning of the first input x and second input y of it? I think it should be index of matrix, but how this matrix is organized? and with any particular order?

```
grd.attr[x,y,"attr_name"]
```

in another word, what is the exact meaning of x,y here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this question:
The fullgrid will generate a matrix/array by your coordinates
with x start with lowest value and y start with highest value
so it should like:

(1,3) (2,3) (3,3)

(1,2) (2,2) (3,2)

(1,1) (2,1) (3,1)

and we know from the origin data frame with coordinates and attributes should  be in:

7 8 9

4 5 6

1 2 3

so if we input

```
grd.attr[2,1,"z1"]
```

it will give us the second row(which is y) and first column(which is x) of the attributes, which is 4!

and if we input

```
grd.attr[2,3,"z1"]
```

it will give us the second row and third col of the attributes, which is 6

all of above is verified is correct

Comment: Well done. I think this is one of the worst parts of sp; I would never do it again like that when redesigning a package like that.

Comment: Thanks! I am studying sp,raster,rgeos, Hopefully there can be a new package which can easily deal with GIS problem such as finding the closest path(not distance) from one place to another place, or from one place to another line/polygon; just based on from google map, If you already know some packages can do it easily, let me know